# Testing TextView text colour using Robolectric for Android

Tags: android, testing, robolectric

I'm trying to TDD/test the text colour of a textView for android. However all of the properties seem to return either 0 or null, does anyone know why?

The code creating the text view:

```
public void setupTextView() {

    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);
    TextView textView = new TextView(this);

    textView.setText(job.getName());

    if (job.getLastBuild().getBuildStatus().equals("SUCCESS")) {

        textView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#007000"));

    } else {

       textView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));

    }

    layout.addView(textView);

}
```

I've ran the application and the code above works.

The properties I've tried accessing in the test code:

```
@Test
public void firstTextViewShouldReflectPassingJobStatus() throws Exception {

    LinearLayout layout = layout = (LinearLayout) activity.findViewById(R.id.layout);

    TextView gomoTextView = (TextView) layout.getChildAt(0);

    System.out.println(gomoTextView.getCurrentTextColor()); //Returns 0
    System.out.println(gomoTextView.getTextColors()); //Returns null
    System.out.println(gomoTextView.getSolidColor()); //Returns 0
    System.out.println(gomoTextView.getCurrentHintTextColor()); //Returns 0

    //I also tried using `Robolectric.shadowOf()`:
    ShadowTextView shadowGomoTextView = Robolectric.shadowOf(gomoTextView);

    System.out.println(shadowGomoTextView.getTextColorHexValue()); //Returns 0
    System.out.println(shadowGomoTextView.getHintColorHexValue()); //Returns null

}
```

**Update to answer comments**

I have a before in the unit test class which calls `onCreate()`:

```
private LinearLayout layout;
private HomeActivity activity;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {

    activity = spy(new HomeActivity());
    Jenkins mockJenkins = TestUtilities.getTestJenkins();
    when(activity.getJenkins()).thenReturn(mockJenkins);

    activity.onCreate(null);
    layout = (LinearLayout) activity.findViewById(R.id.layout);

}
```

And the the onCreate method in the HomeActivity class:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Jenkins jenkins = getJenkins();
    displayJenkins(jenkins);
}
```

And then display jenkins calls a load of other methods which include `setupTextView()`

Comment: Its hard to be sure whats going on without seeing more of your code. where is setupTextView called in the activity lifecycle? are you ensuring that this lifecycle event happens in your test? (or calling it manually at least!)

Comment: Yeah where do you call `setupTextView()` in relation to your test?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking to the [sources](https://github.com/pivotal/robolectric/blob/master/src/main/java/com/xtremelabs/robolectric/shadows/ShadowTextView.java) it's not implemented yet. I would suggest you to implement your own shadow as described [here](http://robolectric.blogspot.nl/2011/01/how-to-create-your-own-shadow-classes.html).

Robolectric 2.0 has been [promoted to the alpha state](http://robolectric.blogspot.nl/2013/01/robolectric-20-alpha-1.html). I think you issue should be fixed during release since they are going to use as much as possible real Android source code.

Comment: Looks like updating to 2.0 has sorted it and not introduced any issues with any existing tests, thanks!